# Only one bootstrap dropdown menu open at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap navbar where the dropdowns open on hover. The problem is, when I click on one link to open the menu and then hover to another link, the initial one stays open. I need it so that only one dropdown menu can be open at a time. I don't mind a js solution.

Here's a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/TcskjKOWfA

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

#main_navbar .navbar-nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  table-layout: auto;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
#main_navbar .navbar-nav > li {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#main_navbar .dropdown-toggle:active,
#main_navbar .open .dropdown-toggle,
#main_navbar .dropdown-toggle:hover,
#main_navbar .open .dropdown-toggle {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000 !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc !important;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc !important;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff !important;
  z-index: 1005;
}
.nav .open>a,
.nav .open>a:focus,
.nav .open>a:hover {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
.nav .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 20px;
  top: 98%;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 230px;
}
.dropdown-header {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
}
li + .dropdown-header {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
  min-width: 400px;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-4 {
  min-width: 766px;
}
.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #000;
  white-space: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.dropdown-menu.multi-column {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#main_navbar .multi-column-dropdown a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#main_navbar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="main_navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <!-- Brands Dropdown -->

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="/brands.html" id="header-brands" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">BRANDS</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-4" role="menu">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li class="dropdown-header">A</li>
              <li><a title="A. Lange &amp; Sohne" href="/brand/a-lange-sohne.html">A. Lange &amp; Sohne</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Audemars Piguet" href="/brand/audemars-piguet.html">Audemars Piguet</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">B</li>
              <li><a title="Baume &amp; Mercier" href="/brand/baume-mercier.html">Baume &amp; Mercier</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Bedat" href="/items.php?brand=74">Bedat</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Bell &amp; Ross" href="/brand/bellross.html">Bell &amp; Ross</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Blancpain" href="/brand/blancpain.html">Blancpain</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Breguet" href="/brand/breguet.html">Breguet</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Breitling" href="/brand/breitling.html">Breitling</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Bremont" href="/items.php?brand=115">Bremont</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Bulgari" href="/brand/bulgari.html">Bulgari</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">C</li>
              <li><a title="Cartier" href="/brand/cartier.html">Cartier</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Chanel" href="/brand/chanel-watches.html">Chanel</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Chopard" href="/brand/chopard.html">Chopard</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li class="dropdown-header">E</li>
              <li><a title="Ebel" href="/brand/ebel.html">Ebel</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">G</li>
              <li><a title="Girard Perregaux" href="/brand/girard-perregaux.html">Girard Perregaux</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Glashutte Original" href="/brand/glashutte-original.html">Glashutte Original</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">H</li>
              <li><a title="Harry Winston" href="/brand/harry-winston.html">Harry Winston</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Hermes" href="/brand/hermes.html">Hermes</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Hublot" href="/brand/hublot.html">Hublot</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">I</li>
              <li><a title="IWC" href="/brand/iwc.html">IWC</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">J</li>
              <li><a title="Jaeger LeCoultre" href="/brand/jaeger-lecoultre.html">Jaeger LeCoultre</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Jaquet Droz" href="/brand/jaquet-droz.html">Jaquet Droz</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li class="dropdown-header">L</li>
              <li><a title="Longines" href="/brand/longines.html">Longines</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">M</li>
              <li><a title="Maurice Lacroix" href="/brand/maurice-lacroix.html">Maurice Lacroix</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Michele" href="/brand/michele.html">Michele</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Montblanc" href="/brand/montblanc-watches.html">Montblanc</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">O</li>
              <li><a title="Omega" href="/brand/omega.html">Omega</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Orbita Watch Winders &amp; Cases" href="/brand/orbita-winders.html">Orbita Watch Winders &amp; Cases</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Oris" href="/brand/oris.html">Oris</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">P</li>
              <li><a title="Panerai" href="/items.php?brand=85">Panerai</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Parmigiani" href="/items.php?brand=118">Parmigiani</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Patek Philippe" href="/items.php?brand=68">Patek Philippe</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Perrelet" href="/items.php?brand=106">Perrelet</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Piaget" href="/items.php?brand=69">Piaget</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li class="dropdown-header">R</li>
              <li><a title="Raymond Weil" href="/brand/raymond-weil.html">Raymond Weil</a>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Rolex" href="/brand/rolex.html">Rolex</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">T</li>
              <li><a title="Tag Heuer" href="/brand/Tag-Heuer.html">Tag Heuer</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">U</li>
              <li><a title="Ulysse Nardin" href="/brand/ulysse-nardin.html">Ulysse Nardin</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">V</li>
              <li><a title="Vacheron Constantin" href="/brand/vacheron-constantin.html">Vacheron Constantin</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Z</li>
              <li><a title="Zenith" href="/brand/zenith.html">Zenith</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- Mens Watches Dropdown -->

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MEN'S WATCHES</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-4" role="menu">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP ALL</li>
              <li><a href="/luxury-watches-for-men.html">All men's watches</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP BY PRICE</li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=0&amp;price_to=2000&amp;size=1,18">under $2,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=2000&amp;price_to=5000&amp;size=1,18">$2,000 - $5,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=5001&amp;price_to=8000&amp;size=1,18">$5,001 - $8,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=8001&amp;price_to=12000&amp;size=1,18">$8,001 - $12,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=12001&amp;size=1,18">$12,001 and up</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP MEN'S SALE</li>
              <li><a href="/luxury-watches-for-men.html">All men's sale</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP SALE BY PRICE</li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=0&amp;price_to=2000&amp;size=1,18&amp;special=1">under $2,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=2000&amp;price_to=5000&amp;size=1,18&amp;special=1">$2,000 - $5,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=5001&amp;price_to=8000&amp;size=1,18&amp;special=1">$5,001 - $8,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=8001&amp;price_to=12000&amp;size=1,18&amp;special=1">$8,001 - $12,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=12001&amp;size=1,18&amp;special=1">$12,001 and up</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP BY MOVEMENT</li>
              <li><a href="/Mens-Quartz-Watches.html">Quartz</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/Mens-Automatic-Watches.html">Automatic</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/Mens-Manual-Wind-Watches.html">Manual Wind</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- Ladies Watches Dropdown -->


    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">WOMEN'S WATCHES</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-4" role="menu">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP ALL</li>
              <li><a href="/luxury-watches-for-women.html">All women's watches</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP BY SALE</li>
              <li><a href="/womens-watches-on-sale.html">Women's watches on sale</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP BY PRICE</li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=0&amp;price_to=2000&amp;size=2">under $2,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=2000&amp;price_to=5000&amp;size=2">$2,000 - $5,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=5001&amp;price_to=8000&amp;size=2">$5,001 - $8,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=8001&amp;price_to=12000&amp;size=2">$8,001 - $12,000</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=12001=8000&amp;size=2">$12,001 and up</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">POLICIES</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column" role="menu" style="padding-top:20px;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li><a href="/policies/returns">Returns and Exchanges</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/policies/payment-shipping">Payment and Shipping</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/policies/warranty">Warranty and Repair</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/policies/international">International Ordering</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/policies/about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/policies/contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/trade_in.php">WATCH TRADE-IN</a>
    </li>


    <!-- Policies Dropdown -->

    <li><a href="/preowned">PREOWNED</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/search.php">ADVANCED SEARCH</a>
    </li>




  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In the code snippet you gave , only one drop down open when hovered, the others are closed. isn't it what you want ?

Comment: @ElSam When you hover and don't click, they do close when you pass on to the next one. But once you click on one of them and the menu opens, then try to hover over to another item, the original open menu stays open.

Comment: @RachelS it's hard to see that in the Bootply. When you click anything it navigates to an external link.

Comment: Click on Men's Watches. The dropdown opens. WHile it's open, hover over Women's Watches. The men's watches dropdown still stays open while the women's one overlays it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could You try this?
I removed `<a href="">` in `<li>` tags

```
<div id="main_navbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <!-- Brands Dropdown -->

    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="/brands.html" id="header-brands">BRANDS</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-4" role="menu">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">A</li>
                        <li><a title="A. Lange &amp; Sohne" href="/brand/a-lange-sohne.html">A. Lange &amp; Sohne</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Audemars Piguet" href="/brand/audemars-piguet.html">Audemars Piguet</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">B</li>
                        <li><a title="Baume &amp; Mercier" href="/brand/baume-mercier.html">Baume &amp; Mercier</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Bedat" href="/items.php?brand=74">Bedat</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Bell &amp; Ross" href="/brand/bellross.html">Bell &amp; Ross</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Blancpain" href="/brand/blancpain.html">Blancpain</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Breguet" href="/brand/breguet.html">Breguet</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Breitling" href="/brand/breitling.html">Breitling</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Bremont" href="/items.php?brand=115">Bremont</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Bulgari" href="/brand/bulgari.html">Bulgari</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">C</li>
                        <li><a title="Cartier" href="/brand/cartier.html">Cartier</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Chanel" href="/brand/chanel-watches.html">Chanel</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Chopard" href="/brand/chopard.html">Chopard</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">E</li>
                        <li><a title="Ebel" href="/brand/ebel.html">Ebel</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">G</li>
                        <li><a title="Girard Perregaux" href="/brand/girard-perregaux.html">Girard Perregaux</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Glashutte Original" href="/brand/glashutte-original.html">Glashutte Original</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">H</li>
                        <li><a title="Harry Winston" href="/brand/harry-winston.html">Harry Winston</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Hermes" href="/brand/hermes.html">Hermes</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Hublot" href="/brand/hublot.html">Hublot</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">I</li>
                        <li><a title="IWC" href="/brand/iwc.html">IWC</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">J</li>
                        <li><a title="Jaeger LeCoultre" href="/brand/jaeger-lecoultre.html">Jaeger LeCoultre</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Jaquet Droz" href="/brand/jaquet-droz.html">Jaquet Droz</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">L</li>
                        <li><a title="Longines" href="/brand/longines.html">Longines</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">M</li>
                        <li><a title="Maurice Lacroix" href="/brand/maurice-lacroix.html">Maurice Lacroix</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Michele" href="/brand/michele.html">Michele</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Montblanc" href="/brand/montblanc-watches.html">Montblanc</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">O</li>
                        <li><a title="Omega" href="/brand/omega.html">Omega</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Orbita Watch Winders &amp; Cases" href="/brand/orbita-winders.html">Orbita Watch Winders &amp; Cases</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Oris" href="/brand/oris.html">Oris</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">P</li>
                        <li><a title="Panerai" href="/items.php?brand=85">Panerai</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Parmigiani" href="/items.php?brand=118">Parmigiani</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Patek Philippe" href="/items.php?brand=68">Patek Philippe</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Perrelet" href="/items.php?brand=106">Perrelet</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Piaget" href="/items.php?brand=69">Piaget</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">R</li>
                        <li><a title="Raymond Weil" href="/brand/raymond-weil.html">Raymond Weil</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Rolex" href="/brand/rolex.html">Rolex</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">T</li>
                        <li><a title="Tag Heuer" href="/brand/Tag-Heuer.html">Tag Heuer</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">U</li>
                        <li><a title="Ulysse Nardin" href="/brand/ulysse-nardin.html">Ulysse Nardin</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">V</li>
                        <li><a title="Vacheron Constantin" href="/brand/vacheron-constantin.html">Vacheron Constantin</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Z</li>
                        <li><a title="Zenith" href="/brand/zenith.html">Zenith</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- Mens Watches Dropdown -->

    <li class="dropdown">
        <a>MEN'S WATCHES</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-4" role="menu">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP ALL</li>
                        <li><a href="/luxury-watches-for-men.html">All men's watches</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP BY PRICE</li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=0&amp;price_to=2000&amp;size=1,18">under $2,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=2000&amp;price_to=5000&amp;size=1,18">$2,000 - $5,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=5001&amp;price_to=8000&amp;size=1,18">$5,001 - $8,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=8001&amp;price_to=12000&amp;size=1,18">$8,001 - $12,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=12001&amp;size=1,18">$12,001 and up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP MEN'S SALE</li>
                        <li><a href="/luxury-watches-for-men.html">All men's sale</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP SALE BY PRICE</li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=0&amp;price_to=2000&amp;size=1,18&amp;special=1">under $2,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=2000&amp;price_to=5000&amp;size=1,18&amp;special=1">$2,000 - $5,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=5001&amp;price_to=8000&amp;size=1,18&amp;special=1">$5,001 - $8,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=8001&amp;price_to=12000&amp;size=1,18&amp;special=1">$8,001 - $12,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=12001&amp;size=1,18&amp;special=1">$12,001 and up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP BY MOVEMENT</li>
                        <li><a href="/Mens-Quartz-Watches.html">Quartz</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Mens-Automatic-Watches.html">Automatic</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Mens-Manual-Wind-Watches.html">Manual Wind</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- Ladies Watches Dropdown -->


    <li class="dropdown">
        <a>WOMEN'S WATCHES</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-4" role="menu">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP ALL</li>
                        <li><a href="/luxury-watches-for-women.html">All women's watches</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP BY SALE</li>
                        <li><a href="/womens-watches-on-sale.html">Women's watches on sale</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">SHOP BY PRICE</li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=0&amp;price_to=2000&amp;size=2">under $2,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=2000&amp;price_to=5000&amp;size=2">$2,000 - $5,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=5001&amp;price_to=8000&amp;size=2">$5,001 - $8,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=8001&amp;price_to=12000&amp;size=2">$8,001 - $12,000</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/items.php?price_from=12001=8000&amp;size=2">$12,001 and up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a>POLICIES</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column" role="menu" style="padding-top:20px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="/policies/returns">Returns and Exchanges</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/policies/payment-shipping">Payment and Shipping</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/policies/warranty">Warranty and Repair</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/policies/international">International Ordering</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/policies/about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/policies/contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/trade_in.php">WATCH TRADE-IN</a></li>


    <!-- Policies Dropdown -->

    <li><a href="/preowned">PREOWNED</a></li>
    <li><a href="/search.php">ADVANCED SEARCH</a></li>




</ul>
```

Comment: I need the first one "brands" to have a link, though.

Comment: I edited. I added <a href="/brands.html"> but i didn't add class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown". Could you check this?

Comment: This works. But it does remove a lot of my styles ;) Is it a problem to remove those attributes or are they just extra in my case?

Comment: Hey I just edited out all the .dropdown-toggle css rules with "a" instead and it works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help :)